# Swift - Converting UIImage to jpegData - [Metal] 9072 by 12198 iosurface is too large for GPU

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to convert images picked from the users camera roll into jpegData for me to upload to a server.

I'm doing the following to covert to Data:

`let imageData: Data? = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)`

This works fine when converting screenshots. But when I attempt to convert an image taken using the device's camera. It gives me the following error:

`[Metal] 9072 by 12198 iosurface is too large for GPU`

It still converts it into data, but the data then just contains a blank image. Not the selected image.

I'm at a loss with where to go with this one, I've tried converting HEIC preloaded onto the device's bundle and it works fine. But when using ones selected from the camera roll, I get the stated error.

Any help would be appreciated. This is the sample code I'm using to test the issue. (I'm aware it's quite pointless in this form)

```
    func convertImage(image: Image?) -> Image? {   //1
        let key = "\(String.random(length: 15))"


        let uiImage: UIImage = image.asUIImage()
        let imageData: Data? = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)

        guard let imageData = imageData else { return nil }
        
        let encodedImage = imageData.base64EncodedString()
        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        let localImageUrl = (documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent(key))
        guard let localImageUrl = localImageUrl else {
            return nil
        }
        try! encodedImage.write(to: localImageUrl, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        
        guard let fileContents = try? String(contentsOf: localImageUrl) else {
            return nil
        }

        let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: fileContents, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
        
        return (Image(uiImage: decodedimage ?? UIImage(named: "placeholder")!))
    }
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct UploadTesting: View {
    @ObservedObject var crViewModel = ChatroomsViewModel()
    
    @State var showImagePicker = false
    @State var selectedImage: Image? = nil
    
    @State var convertedImage: Image?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Select") {
                showImagePicker.toggle()
            }
            
            selectedImage?.resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            
            Button("Convert") {


                convertedImage = crViewModel.convertImage(image: selectedImage)
            }
            
            convertedImage?.resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 200, height: 200).background(Color.red)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
            ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage)
        }

    }
}
```

Video of issue: https://streamable.com/h0uqly